# Should I pass data between components using React-Navigation or Redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Let's imagine I have an app with a MoviesList component consisting of SectionList of movies' names and onPress of each item in the list, I get redirected to the MovieDetails page with all the relevant data about that movie.

```
StackNavigator({
    list: { screen: MoviesList },
    details: { screen: MoviesDetails },
})
```

Could I pass the object, consisting this relevant data from the SectionList component to the MovieDetails component using params of React-Navigation or it's better, from the performance point of view, to handle this in a Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to pass *something* to the `MoviesDetails` screen.

It may be an id, that you'll use on the screen to get a movie object from redux, or you may as well pass the entire object to `MoviesDetails`, which will very likely be more convenient from developer point of view.

Performance-wise, this will make no difference, but you may want to consider [deep linking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/linking) (say somebody opens the app via a browser and in that case, all your screen gets is some movie id).

Comment: I see. Appreciate your help!